# 'CCHttpRequest' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to use CCHttpRequest in my game to download images from the server.
I have

```
#include "cocos-ext.h"
```

in my Header File and have

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static
```

in Android.mk.

I'm still getting `'CCHttpRequest' was not declared in this scope` error.
I am using  cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.2 and can see the files in  Cocos2dx directory.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I just needed to use namespace cocos2d::extension

```
using namespace cocos2d::extension;
```